# Show a components of div tag based on condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

Hi Friends my second question here, got an excellent answer for the first one:

I have displayed a div tag as below:

```
<div class='tabHeaderSection cb'>           
    <ul>
        <li >My Development </li>
        <li>Impact </li>
        <li>Events</li>
        <li >Marketplace </li>
        <li>Payment Notification </li>                 
</div>
```

Now i want payment notification to be shown based on one condition, so I kep it in outputpanel and rendered as below:

```
<div class='tabHeaderSection cb'>           
    <ul>
        <li >My Development </li>
        <li>Impact </li>
        <li>Events</li>
        <li >Marketplace </li>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(contactstatus=='Offered AFL - awaiting response',TRUE,FALSE)}" styleclass="tabHeaderSection cb">               

        <li>Payment Notification </li> 

       </apex:outputpanel>                      
        </ul>
    <span class='cb'></span>
</div>
```

But the problem here is when I keep outputpanel inside div tag all the styling used in div class is gone - I need both styling form div tag and render based on one condition. How is that possible??
Waiting for your reply guys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `apex:outputPanel` by default is rendered as a `<div>`, so that messes up your unordered list. It can also be rendered as a `<span>` or, under some conditions without an html element. This can be controlled with the layout attribute. Use `layout="block"` for a `<div>`, `layout="inline"` for a `<span>` or `layout="none"` for nothing. See the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm) of the outputpanel, specifically the "layout" part of the attribute section. Note that there are some side-effects of unrendered outputpanels with `layout="none"`.

Comment: it worked with layout="none". As of now I am not working on unrendered outputpanels :) - so its working fine for me!!